# Render Grease Pencil like texture brush in painting apps (e.g. Photoshop)

Tags: materials, shaders, grease-pencil, 2d

I'm talking about this kind of texture brush:

[image]

(made in Photoshop)

I'm aware of grease pencil `Surface > Stroke` option, but it's not enough to emulate Photoshop (and most painting apps)'s texture brushes. For example, Photoshop's brushes essentially consist of 3 main components:

- Brush Tip: A repetitive pattern
- Dual Brush: Another different repetitive pattern
- Texture: A texture overlay

And you can combine all three in some Blend Mode, like multiply, color dodge, or height (with some limitation). This is what makes PS's brush system powerful. Grease pencil's stroke texture is basically just Photoshop's brush tip.

I suppose there might be a way to actually 99% emulate PS or even Krita's brushes, with some node-based materials or something. But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just my opinion, but I think it's not possible. The main reason being that PS/Krita are bitmap based, so you have a per-pixel control. Blender's GP on the other hand just saves paths, not pixels, a lot more like a vector based program (Flash, Inkscape, etc...). Blender's textured brushes do a good job at faking the look, but it will always be limited by comparison. On the other hand, things like stroke interpolations are only possible because it uses paths. So, you know, you win some, you lose some?